# Is Windows 10 usable without working graphics card?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, cpu

Short story: A few days ago I fried the videocard/chip of my laptop. Apparently leaving EUIV running on a hot day wasn't the smartest decision. Windows crashed, gave a `video_TDR_failure` on a blue screen riddled with vertical lines, and restarted. Each consequent restart would do the same, although since the second time it now first stops at start-up repair.
Broken laptop, yada yada, why the question? Well, my Debian partition still works (or, well, after I reinstalled it, but it works now). It also gives visual output without any visual glitches or tears. So if Debian can work solely on the cpu, maybe Windows can do so as well?

Therefore: Is it possible to get Windows 10 up and running without a properly functioning graphics card?

Comment: If Debian is working with a GUI, then the problem here isn't the GPU, it is working fine... The problem is Windows. Have you tried reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Maybe it has dual graphics......